# Cast Json result to template T list or array

Tags: json, .net-core, webapi

I am trying to create a table (list or array) of type T (to be determined at runtime, based on parameters) from HttpContext. I can create each individual element (reportRow below) and have it successfuly cast as T, but can't figure out how to combine them into a list of type T (result).  My errors include invalid arguments (all are valid) and unable to cast my specifc class to the generic class. All "solutions" I have found require me to use T, but I run into the  "T is a variable not a type" error, so I am trying to use options that let me pass T as a variable.

```
var reportContext = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonNode>();
var reportData = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(reportContext.ToString())["ReportData"];
int count = reportData.AsArray().Count();
Type T = Type.GetType("Namespace.Shared.MyDataClass, Namespace.Shared"); //hardcoded only for testing
dynamic result = Activator.CreateInstance(T, typeof(List<>));

              // Also tried: dynamic result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(T));  
                
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)             
{
byte[] byteArrayLoop = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reportData[i].ToJsonString());
MemoryStream streamLoop = new(byteArrayLoop);
var reportRow = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(streamLoop, T, options);
result.Add(reportRow);
}
```